# Specifying datacontext to a generic Viewmodel

Tags: viewmodel, mvvm-light, datacontext

I have defined a viewmodel like

```
   public class DataGridBaseViewModel<T>:ViewModelBase
    {
    ObservableCollection<T> DataCollection;
public abstract void Initialize();


    }
public class Grid1ViewModel:DataGridBaseViewModel<MyModel1>
{
public void override Initialize()
{
DataCollection = new ObservableCollection<MyModel1>();
}
}
public class Grid2ViewModel:DataGridBaseViewModel<MyModel2>
{
public void override Initialize()
{
DataCollection = new ObservableCollection<MyModel2>();
}
}
```

Now I have 2 datagrids which should display MyModel1 and MyModel2. How can I specify the datacontext of the view.

Please help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: please post the xaml from your view

Answer (score -1):

My views are usercontrols.  I define my viewmodels in the viewmodel locator and then use the following in xaml to bind the view DATACONTEXT to the viewmodel:

```
<UserControl x:Class="FTC.View.EmployeeListView"
            xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
            xmlns:cmd="http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvmlight"
            mc:Ignorable="d" 
            DataContext="{Binding EmployeeList_VM, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">
```

So just use the above example to bind the datacontext of your datagrids to the viewmodels

Comment: This is not an answer - no details about generics.